# How Can I execute this API using Zoho Deluge?

Tags: zoho

Could you please help me with that? I did try my best to get this function up and running?

Here are the articles that I viewed-
https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/script/invoking-a-function.html

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://gw.cmtelecom.com/v1.0/message' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
"messages": {
"authentication": {
"producttoken": "test"
},
"msg": [
  {
    "from": "00919538893819",
    "to": [
      {
        "number": "00918892449978"
      }
    ],
    "body": {
      "type": "auto",
      "content": "This is a WhatsApp message"
    },
    "allowedChannels": [
      "WhatsApp"
    ],
    "richContent": {
      "conversation": [
        {
          "template": {
            "whatsapp": {
              "namespace": "5c198301_106c_4fc2_a2f6_7556d8847746",
              "element_name": "otp",
              "language": {
                "policy": "deterministic",
                "code": "en"
              },
              "components": [
                {
                  "type": "body",
                  "parameters": [
                    {
                      "type": "text",
                      "text": "Dhanush"
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "text",
                      "text": "627728289"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
}
}'
```

Is there a different way we could execute this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you asking for help improving the code, or does it fail? If it fails see "[mcve]". I would write the content to a file and tell curl to send it, rather than try to generate that command in a script or the command-line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define a variable with the JSON data first, and then pass the data as a string to invokeUrl.

See the following example:

```
void APICall()
{
    data = {"messages":{"authentication":{"producttoken":"******"},"msg":{{"from":"00919538893819","to":{{"number":"00918892449978"}},"body":{"type":"auto","content":"This is a WhatsApp message"},"allowedChannels":{"WhatsApp"},"richContent":{"conversation":{{"template":{"whatsapp":{"namespace":"5c198301_106c_4fc2_a2f6_7556d8847746","element_name":"otp","language":{"policy":"deterministic","code":"en"},"components":{{"type":"body","parameters":{{"type":"text","text":"Dhanush"},{"type":"text","text":"627728289"}}}}}}}}}}}}};
    
    response = invokeUrl
    [
        url: "https://gw.cmtelecom.com/v1.0/message"
        type: POST
        parameters: data.toString()
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    ];
    
    info response;
}
```

Please, do not post API Authentication Tokens in your quetions!